# Adding data to mongoDb using laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I am adding data to mongoDb using laravel :

**In Model:** `Banner.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Mongo;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'banner';
    protected $guarded = ['_id'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        '_id',
        'url',
        'width',
        'height',
    ];
}
```

**In Controller :** `BannerController.php`

```
use App\Models\Mongo\Banner;
use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;
public function store(Request $request)
{
   Banner::create([
     '_id'   => new ObjectId(),
     'url'   => 'test.jpg',
     'width' => 960,
     'height'=> 300
   ]);
   return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success'
    ], 200);
}
```

**ERROR :** `message: "Call to a member function prepare() on null"`

Or I tried another way, instead of saving with model class I use Repositories : `BannerRepository.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories\MongoDB;
use App\Models\Mongo\Banner;
use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;
class BannerRepository extends MongoDBBaseRepository
{
    public function model()
    {
        return Banner::class;
    }
}
```

In controller :

```
use App\Models\Mongo\Banner;
use App\Repositories\MongoDB\BannerRepository;
use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;

   /**
     * @var BannerRepository
     */
   protected $bannerRepository;

public function __construct(
        BannerRepository $bannerRepository
 ) {
        $this->bannerRepository = $bannerRepository;
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->bannerRepository->getModel()->create([
     '_id'   => new ObjectId(),
     'url'   => 'test.jpg',
     'width' => 960,
     'height'=> 300
   ]);
   return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success'
    ], 200);
}
```

**ERROR :** `Return value of App\\Repositories\\MongoDBBaseRepository::getModel() must be an instance of Jenssegers\\Mongodb\\Eloquent\\Model, instance of App\\Models\\Mongo\\Banner returned"`

I have tried two ways. And both error. Don't know where I did wrong. Please give me your opinion. I'm new to laravel so it's a bit difficult. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`

Try to use Mongo `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;`

Something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Mongo;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#eloquent).

Comment: Thank you..This is a good answer